# Can color palette be specified for rasterImage?

Tags: r, r-raster

Title says it all, pretty much.  So far as I can tell,  trying to pass a simple color palette by using the `col` argument, e.g.,  `rasterImage(mydata,xleft=1,ybottom=1,xright=2,ytop=2,col=grey(0:4095/4096))` fails. What's more confusing is that the default palette seems to depend on the class of `mydata` .

If I have a matrix, `rasterImage(as.raster(mymatrix), {etc}` plots in grayscale, while using a `RasterLayer` object, `rasterImage(as.raster(myRaster),{etc}` plots in a topo color set.

Any suggestions for alternative (fast) tools to plot large images gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just using  `useRaster=TRUE` inside the basic `graphics:image` function is fine.

This works, and very quickly (as opposed to not rasterizing a large matrix), with a matrix or a RasterLayer object:

```
image(mydata, useRaster=TRUE, col={whatever})
```

I should have tried that before going off into wrapper functions.