# plot rasterImage with different color palette and color scale

Tags: r, image, plot

I'm trying to create an image with a scale following

```
m3 <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
plot(NA, type="n", xlim=c(1, nc), ylim=c(1, nr), axes=FALSE, asp=1,
  xlab="", ylab="")
m3 <- abs(m3)/max(abs(m3))
rasterImage(m3, xleft=1, xright=nc, ybottom=1, ytop=nr)
```

On this plot they suggest image

[Can color palette be specified for rasterImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835412/can-color-palette-be-specified-for-rasterimage)

that seems to work well in this way

```
rasterImage(m3, xleft=1, xright=nc, ybottom=1, ytop=nr, interpolate=FALSE)
image(m3, useRaster=TRUE)
```

but I did not manage to make it work

```
image(m3, useRaster=TRUE, col="blue")
```

I also need a color scale like this

http://menugget.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html

someone know how to do it with a single function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `image.scale` function:

http://menugget.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html

```
 im <- abs(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10))
 mI <- max(im, na.rm=TRUE)
 rM <- im 
 rM[is.na(rM)] <- 0
 colRamp <- colorRamp(c("black", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "purple"))
 col <- rgb(colRamp(rM/mI), maxColorValue=255)

 p <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(im), ncol=ncol(im), byrow=TRUE)

 p[,] <- col

layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=2, ncol=1), heights=c(4,1))
layout.show(2)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
breaks <- seq(min(rM/mI), max(rM/mI),length.out=100)

 plot(NA, type="n", xlim=c(1, ncol(p)), ylim=c(1, nrow(p)),
              xlab="", ylab="", xaxs="i", yaxs="i", axes=FALSE, asp=1)
 rasterImage(as.raster(p), xleft=1, xright=ncol(p), ybottom=1, ytop=nrow(p),
                        interpolate=TRUE)

par(mar=c(3,1,1,1)) 
pal.1=colorRampPalette(c("black", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "purple"), space="rgb")
image.scale(m3, col=pal.1(length(breaks)-1), breaks=breaks, horiz=TRUE)
```